Laravel "failed (40: Too many levels of symbolic links)" with storage files
I am using Hostinger VPS for hosting my Laravel project and Ubuntu 22.04 with CloudPanel.
I have a directory storage/app/public/icons when I'm trying to get an image from that directory, I got a 403 response.
I have tried to run php artisan storage:unlink and then php artisan storage:link and I got the same error.
And I have tried to create the link manually with the absolute path and I got the same error also.
I can see the link in the /public directory but it is not working.
When I saw the logs from the panel, I have got this error "failed (40: Too many levels of symbolic links)".
Sorry but I am not familiar with Linux so what should I do.

it mostly says that you have a loop of symbolic links

I couldn't find any loop and when I put the environment to local it works fine but this problem appears when it is production ! @N69S

Have you checked all symbolic links on your production platform ? run find . -type l -ls in your server and add the results to your question.
